# Unable to resize "Skype for business" contact list

Tags: windows-10, skype, skype-for-business, skype-for-windows-10

[image]

Yo,

I am unable to resize the contact list. When I hover over the divider line the cursor changes to the "Horizontal resize" cursor (the double ended arrow), but when I drag side to side it only moves a couple of pixels and then gets stuck and goes no further.

I have tried setting the window to a variety of sizes and in a variety of "aero-snap" positions but have had no luck no matter what size or position.

Please help, I would like to be able to see the full names of the people who I am talking to in the sidebar.

Cheers

Comment: What the version of skype do you have? Just try to upgrade/update the skype. https://support.microsoft.com/zh-cn/help/4010274/adds-support-to-resize-the-width-of-the-tab-list-with-a-splitter-bar-i

Comment: @OOOO I just downloaded the latest update and my system reported that it is already installed

Answer (score 0):

I had to dig around in the settings. I found a setting under "IM" - "Enable Tabbed conversations" with a subsetting "make tabs only one line". After toggling that and mucking around I managed to unlock the resizing feature. Now I am able to resize no dramas.

Comment: Tried this, did not help in my case :-(